# Show that $\phi : \mathbb{Z}_2\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_4^*$ is an isomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

I know that $\mathbb{Z}_2=\{0,1\}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_4^*=\{1,3\}$

So $\phi$ is defined as:$\phi(0)=1$ and $\phi(1)=3$

Clearly then it is bijective since every element of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ maps to exactly one unique element in $\mathbb{Z}_4^*$ and vice versa.

However to show that it is an isomorphism it needs to satisfy: $\phi(a*b)=\phi(a)*\phi(b)$, which in this case it does not since $\phi(0*1)=\phi(0)=1\neq\phi(0)*\phi(1)$. Am I missing something or misunderstand something? Any nudge in the correct direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You confused the group compositions. One is multiplication, the other addition. Since both groups have two elements, by Lagrange they have to be isomorphic. So actually you don't have to search for an isomorphism.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is considered a group with the addition operation while $\mathbb{Z}_4^*$ with the multiplication operation.

Comment: In $\mathbb{Z}_2=\{0,1\}$  the group operation is addition mod 2 whereas in $\mathbb{Z}_4^*=\{1,3\}$ the operation 1s multiplication mod 4. So $\phi(0*1)=\phi(1)$.

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakisd'oh! Of course. My mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comments have noted, $\mathbb{Z}/(2)$ is an additive group and $(\mathbb{Z}/(4))^*$ is a multiplicative group. So, you want $\phi(a+b) = \phi(a)\phi(b)$. You have
$$\phi(0+1) = \phi(1) = 3 = \phi(0)\phi(1),$$
$$\phi(0+0) = \phi(0) = 1 = \phi(0)\phi(0),$$
$$\phi(1+1) = \phi(0) = 1 = \phi(1)\phi(1).$$

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I missed that they have different operations.